# PostgreSQL 15.2. Setting up logical replication

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 15.2. I created and populated the tables on the publish side and the subscribe side:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(a int, b text, PRIMARY KEY(a));
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three');
```

Successfully configured logical replication. When I change data on publish side: `UPDATE t1 SET b = 'aaa' WHERE a = 1;` I see that the data has changed on the subscription side as well. But when I add a newline on the subscribe side: `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4, 'bbb');` and then add a line on the publish side: `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4, 'four');` a conflict occurs and data from the publication is not transferred to the subscription.

I need to make sure that, regardless of conflicts, the data from the publication always replaces the conflicting lines on the subscription side. I didn't find a way to do this. Advise how to do it?

Comment: Read [Conflicts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-conflicts.html).

Comment: I read Documentation -> PostgreSQL 15 -> 31.5. Conflicts, it says that you need to remove the conflict line on the subscription side. But I need to do this removal automatically, for which I want to write a python function that would do this. But for this I need to know the value of the primary key, the row in which the conflict occurred. I don't know how to do it.